# how to configure 'dynamic key' in properties file loaded using @PropertySource in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring 4 `@Configuration` annotation, this is how I configure a properties file and refer in my application:

**src/main/resources/errors.properties**

```
name.empty.error=name is empty
department.empty.error=department is empty
```

Java code configuration and usage:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:errors.properties")
public class Sample {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public void usage() {
        String errorText = env.getProperty("name.empty.error");
    }
```

I'd like to specify 'key' of my errors.properties in the following manner:

```
{0}.empty.error={0} is empty
```

so that the `usage()` method would call something like

```
String errorText1 = env.getProperty("{}.empty.error", "name");
String errorText2 = env.getProperty("{}.empty.error", "department");
```

How to do this? I remember something like this existed in Struts error message handling.

Comment: I'd say that you're overthinking it, why do something contrived like this instead of adding the property of "`empty.error.suffix=is empty`" and only prepending name of the field before sending it to the view layer?

Comment: Your suggestion also makes sense, I could do that as well but using some `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` or using `String.format`. Let's say I have the case where I need to pass two parameters to build a value like "name is empty in createEmployee". Here, `name` and `createEmployee` are the two parameters. In this case if I can pass them and in the properties file if I can read as `{0}` and `{1}` that would be better, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `MessageSource`, which is an interface for resolving messages. [ResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html)  is `MessageSource` implementation which can read from properties file.

You'll need to configure it (I have not tried to compile the source)

```
@Bean
MessageSource messageSource() {
     ResourceBundleMessageSource source=new  ResourceBundleMessageSource();
     source.setBasenames("messages");
     return source;
}
```

You'll have to wire it and in the code you would call:

```
String errorText1 = source.getMessage("empty.error", "name", Locale.US);
```

and in your messages file you would have:

```
empty.error = {0} is empty
```

As a bonus, your app will be ready for internalization.

Comment: Perfect, I will add the Spring configuration approach also. Sorry for late acceptance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this,

```
 String errorText1 = env.getProperty(String.format("%s.empty.error", "name"));
 String errorText2 = env.getProperty(String.format("%s.empty.error", "department"));
```

Edit:

It makes no sense, if you use this just to get these specific values from the property file.

But if these values are decided during the run-time (give that all these properties are available in the property file).

You can use,

```
 String errorText1 = env.getProperty(String.format("%s.empty.error", dynamic-property-value-goes-here));
```

Comment: looks like a great idea, +1

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `String errorText1 = env.getProperty("name.empty.error");
 String errorText2 = env.getProperty("department.empty.error");` just by evaluating the static placeholders. This doesn't seem to be what OP is asking.

Comment: @kryger Yes the simplification is correct, But, if there is a requirement so that this "name" is dynamically used, then my approach is correct. I thought about the question that way.

Comment: @kryger I understood now what you meant here. Actually I assumed  Diyoda reply that the value is passed dynamically not static, otherwise yes it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Regarding OP, My question was how to use this via Property Resources, though `String.format` does similar job if not fully

Answer (score 0):

We can use `MessageSource` interface for resolving messages.

`ResourceBundleMessageSource` is `MessageSource` implementation which can read from properties file.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html

and then call the `getMessage()` method.

`String org.springframework.context.MessageSource.getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale)`

---

**messages.properties** file in classpath [src/main/resources/]

```
empty.error = {0} is empty
```

**Spring-config file**

```
<bean id="messageSource1" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basenames">
    <value>messages</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

**Usage in Java class:**

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource1;

public MessageSource getMessageSource1() {
  return messageSource1;
}

public void setMessageSource1(MessageSource messageSource1) {
  this.messageSource1 = messageSource1;
}
```

**// exact usage in your Java class method**

```
String [] params = new String[]{"value1"};
log.info(this.messageSource1.getMessage("empty.error", params ,"", Locale.US));
```